Switch from INotifyPropertyChanged to ObservableObject
Good Afternoon, I'm working on a runtime globalization in wpf, .net 8.0 framework, mvvm community toolkit. I managed to do it without the toolkit (INotifyPropertyChanged, #commented code), but i can't switch to ObservableObject way, can someone help me, tqvm.
MainWindow1.xaml
<Window x:Class="MvvmTutorials.ToolkitIntro.Views.MainWindow1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MvvmTutorials.ToolkitIntro"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvmTutorials.ToolkitIntro.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow1" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:LanguageManager />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <!--<ComboBox x:Name="LanguageList" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="10" SelectionChanged="LanguageList_SelectionChanged" />-->
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Langs}" SelectedItem="{Binding LangItem}" Margin="10" />

        <TextBlock FontSize="20" Margin="10" Text="{Binding [String1],Source={x:Static vm:LanguageManager.InstanceF}}" />
        <TextBox FontSize="20" Margin="10" Text="{Binding [String2],Source={x:Static vm:LanguageManager.InstanceF},Mode=OneWay}" />
        <Button FontSize="20" Margin="10" Content="{Binding [String3],Source={x:Static vm:LanguageManager.InstanceF}}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

MainWindow1.xaml.cs
namespace MvvmTutorials.ToolkitIntro.Views;

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow1 : Window
{
    public MainWindow1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //LanguageList.ItemsSource = new List<string>
        //{
        //    "en-US",
        //    "ja",
        //};
    }

    //private void LanguageList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    LanguageManager.InstanceF.ChangeLanguage(new CultureInfo((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem.ToString()));
    //}
}

LanguageManager.cs
namespace MvvmTutorials.ToolkitIntro;

//public partial class LanguageManager : INotifyPropertyChanged
public partial class LanguageManager : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private List<string> _langs = new List<string>()
    {
        "en-US",
        "ja",
        "zh-CN",
    };

    [ObservableProperty]  
    private string _langItem = "en-US";

    partial void OnLangItemChanged(string value)
    {
        CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(value);
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

        //MessageBox.Show(this["String1"]);
    }

    private static readonly Lazy<LanguageManager> _lazyZ = new Lazy<LanguageManager>(() => new LanguageManager());

    public static LanguageManager InstanceF => _lazyZ.Value;

    private readonly ResourceManager _resourceManagerS;

    public LanguageManager()
    {
        _resourceManagerS = new ResourceManager("MvvmTutorials.ToolkitIntro.Resources.Lang1", typeof(LanguageManager).Assembly);
    }

    public string this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            if (name == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
            }

            return _resourceManagerS.GetString(name);
        }
    }

    //public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    //public void ChangeLanguage(CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    //{
    //    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    //    CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

    //    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("item[]"));
    //}
}

I want the globalization can works with ObservableObject way. However, i don't know how to switch PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("item[]")); in ObservableObject way (MVVM Community Toolkit).

OnPropertyChanged("item[]") https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/blob/7b53ae23dfc6a7fb12d0fc058b89b6e948f48448/src/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm/ComponentModel/ObservableObject.cs#L67
ObeservableObject does not introduce anything new, it's barely a helper wrapper for convenience, it still contains all basic stuff.

The question is unclear. There aren't two "ways". ObservableObject implements INotifyPropertyChanged. That interface is a .NET interface, not an external type, and is required for updates to data bound objects.

The docs for the MVVM Community Toolkit ObservableObject show it provides a SetProperty similar to your own, that doesn't require a property name. In fact, you could make your own method work exactly the same by adding the CallerMemberName attribute to the property name parameter. In the doc example,  SetProperty(ref name, value); sets and raises the event for Name

Simple put, what i not able to do is remind "this" to update the ui by using ObservableProperty. If not mistaken, i think PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("item[]")); is used to remind "this" to update the ui.

if i want add
[ObservableProperty]
private string[] item;
-> public string this[string name] { } line will error
The type 'LanguageManager' already contains a definition for 'Item'
it means that Item[] is initially created in "this".

Yes just like its documented

See the following note in Using Indexers:

Declaring an indexer will automatically generate a property named Item on the object. The Item property is not directly accessible from the instance member access expression. Additionally, if you add your own Item property to an object with an indexer, you'll get a CS0102 compiler error. To avoid this error, use the IndexerNameAttribute to rename the indexer as detailed below.

This means you can not declare a (default-named) indexer and an ObservableProperty named Item at the same time:
public partial class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    // generates a property named Item
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string[] item;

    // also generates a property named Item, hence CS0102
    public string this[string key] => "something";
}

In your case it seems however useless to have the additional property at all, since you can simply use the ObservableObject's OnPropertyChanged method:
public void ChangeLanguage(CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

    OnPropertyChanged("Item[]"); // upper case!
}


You may want to avoid the magic string and use the constant defined by the Binding class Binding.IndexerName like OnPropertyChanged(Binding.IndexerName);

Not bad, but it would create a dependency to the Binding class in PresentationFramework.dll. You may not want to have that in a view model.

PresentationFramework.dll contains a few (very few) useful types (and static methods) you may want to use in the view model: BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization, Application.Current.Dispatcher or CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView. I agree that the dependency to the Binding type is avoidable but Binding.IndexerName significantly improves the readability, I would argue. One might wonder what "Item" property the change event is raised for. We could also create a delegating field in the App class to forward the constant. In general, it's good to have a choice I guess.

I have found the solution myself. the workable code is
InstanceF.OnPropertyChanged("item[]");
Thanks for the help btw.

@LeongWeiSheng OnPropertyChanged("item[]") is wrong. It must be OnPropertyChanged("Item[]") - as explained in the answer. And the InstanceF part is totally odd, because there is no mention of it in the question. What is is supposed to be?
